# Which SDK Version variable requires REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-package-managers

The documentation for 'REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES' says:

> Note:If your app is targeting API level higher than 25 you need to hold REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in order to launch the application installer.

Does this refer to "minSdkVersion=26" or "targetSdkVersion=26" when it says "targeting"?

Comment: Probably target, but its really both. Target means the installation device version

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when Google uses the verb "targeting", they refer to `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: And that's the same as Build.VERSION.SDK_INT?

Comment: @Bungles: No, that is the version of Android that the device is running.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can it be that even if my app target SDK is 25, app installation fails because I hold only INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and not also  REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES when running on android 8? I'm getting the following exception:  "...Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10045 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES..."

Comment: @TalKanel: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you can provide a [mcve]. `INSTALL_PACKAGES` has `android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged"`, so ordinary Android SDK apps cannot hold it.